# Externals defined in webpack.config still getting error module not found

Tags: webpack, webpack-externals

I have defined externals in webpack.config for material-ui

```
module.exports = [{
  entry: ...
  output:...
  externals: {
    react: {
      commonjs: "react",
      commonjs2: "react"
    },
    "material-ui": {
      commonjs: "material-ui",
      commonjs2: "material-ui"
    }
  },
  module: ...
}];
```

Still its giving error like-

> Cannot resolve module 'material-ui/IconButton'......

In my entry js file, I have

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import IconButton from "material-ui/IconButton";
.....
.....
```

Comment: See this related issue. https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/1726

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I solved it. External expects complete path.

So either,

```
import {IconButton} from "material-ui"
```

or

```
externals: {
  "material-ui/IconButton": {
    commonjs: "material-ui/IconButton",
    ...
  }
}
```

will work. Ofcourse, second option is not reasonable here

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! I'll also add here, the string value is case sensitive, ex `vue` does not work, but `Vue` does.

Comment: thank you very much! Using your method solved my problem. The problem scenario I encountered is as follows: My component library, component A needs to refer to another component B in the component library through [npm package name], so I use externals; and because I use [npm link] for real-time development , So when the local [lib cache folder] is emptied during the component library packaging process, it prompts [Cannot resolve module'library name/lib/component B'].